# If $P$ is a projection and $D$ is of trace class, is it true that $\mathrm{tr}(PDP)=\mathrm{tr}(DP)$?

Tags: hilbert-spaces, self-adjoint-operators

According to Varadarajan$^{1}$, in a separable Hilbert space,

> If $A$ is of trace class and $B$ is any bounded operator, $AB$ and $BA$ are of
> trace class; and moreover, $tr(AB) = tr(BA)$.

Orthogonal projections are bounded, since $\|Px\|\le \|x\|$, so if $D$ is of trace class, then according to the above statement, $DP$ is also trace class and $\mathrm{tr}(P(DP))=\mathrm{tr}((DP)P)=\mathrm{tr}(D(PP))=\mathrm{tr}(DP)$
since $P^2=P$.

However, I have some doubts because Varadarajan consistently writes $\mathrm{tr}(PDP)$ without this simplification. Where am I wrong?

---

$^{1}$Varadarajan, *Geometry of Quantum Theory* Springer 1985, Second edition, p. 84

Comment: You are correct that $\mathrm{tr}(PDP) = \mathrm{tr}(DP)$. I don’t know the reason why the author chose to write $\mathrm{tr}(PDP)$ more. Maybe because in this form, it’s clear that if $D$ is positive (resp, self-adjoint) then $\mathrm{tr}(PDP)$ is positive (resp, real)?